# access netezza database with python without driver from IBM

Tags: python, netezza

Is there a way to query a netezza database without explicitly installing its driver? I am using ubuntu 64 bit OS, our IT support says the driver they have only works on red hat systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on the JDBC driver, you could use the Python, [`jaydebeapi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) module, with the driver to connect to the server. Note that there are a couple quirks involved. Namely things like `boolean` datatypes.

Comment: Thanks. I got an error: jpype._jexception.NzSQLExceptionPyRaisable: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the host name and port are cor
rect and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.netezza.Driver",
                          "jdbc:netezza://db_url:5480/db",
                          ["usr","pass"],
                          "./nzjdbc3.jar",)

Comment: @BoQiang -- Either you have the wrong host/port or there is not connectivity from your computer to the host/port. Resolve that issue and try again.

Comment: I get TypeError: Class org.netezza.Driver is not found

Comment: @diman82 please open an issue and provide the code you've used and the error you're encountering. Feel free to comment and I'll check it out.

Comment: @joebeeson No need to open a new issue, there is already an exisiting one: https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/issues/85#issuecomment-488097808

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyodbc`.

> pyodbc is an open source Python module that makes accessing ODBC
>   databases simple. It implements the DB API 2.0 specification but is
>   packed with even more Pythonic convenience.

On Ubuntu systems, all you need to do is run

```
sudo apt install unixodbc-dev
```

before attempting

```
pip install pyodbc
```

See more details from [Installing pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install).

Comment: Thanks. In http://www.unixodbc.org/, I did not find it contains a driver for Netezza. Do you have any examples for how to set it up? Thanks again.

Comment: @BoQiang Have a look at the pyodbc doc.